how to send a http only cookie from backend
I am trying to create authentication for an admin panel using JWT tokens and HTTP-only cookies with Express.js. When I send a request from the frontend, it gives a successful response but doesn’t return any cookie. However, when I try the same request from Postman, it returns the cookie as expected.
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (loading) return;
    setLoading(true); // Start loading

    try {
        const response = await axios.post(
            `${import.meta.env.VITE_BACKEND_URI}/adminLogin`,
            { Id: id, Password: password }, { withCredentials:true }
        );

        if (response.status === 200) {
            navigate('/Home');
        }
    } catch (error) {
        setError(error.response?.data?.error || "Login failed. Please check your internet or try again later.");
    } finally {setLoading(false);}
};


After clicking the submit button, I am redirected to the /Home route.
below is the api endpoint where i am creating and sending the cookie
import express from 'express';
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';

dotenv.config();
const router = express.Router();

router.post('/', (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { Id, Password } = req.body;

        console.log(process.env.ADMIN_ID === String(Id));
        console.log(process.env.ADMIN_PASSWORD === String(Password));
        
        if (process.env.ADMIN_ID === String(Id) && process.env.ADMIN_PASSWORD === String(Password)) {
            const token = jwt.sign({ id: Id, password: Password }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, { expiresIn: '1h' });
            
            res.cookie("jwtToken", token, {
                httpOnly: true,
                secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production', 
                sameSite: "Lax",
                maxAge: 3600 * 1000,
                path: '/', 
            });
            
            console.log("correct");
            res.sendStatus(200);
        } else {
            res.status(401).json({ error: "invalid credentials" });
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        res.status(500).json({ error: "Internal Server Error" });
    }
});

export default router;


this is my server.js file i think this has all the required middleware if i am missing any please tell me
import express from "express";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';
import cors from "cors";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import connectDB from "./config/db.js";
import loginRoute from "./routes/Login.js";
import signUpRoute from "./routes/SignUp.js";
import authorizationRoute from "./routes/Authorize.js";
import deleteUserRoute from "./routes/deleteUser.js";
import sendEmailRoute from "./routes/Subscriber.js";
import sendInquiriesRoute from "./routes/Inquiries.js";
import adminLoginRoute from "./routes/AdminLogin.js";
import tokenRoute from "./middleware/auth.js";

dotenv.config();
connectDB();

const server = express();
const port = process.env.PORT_NO || 3000;

server.use(bodyParser.json());
server.use(cookieParser());

server.use(cors({
    origin: ["http://localhost:4000", "http://localhost:5173"],
    credentials: true,
}));

// Home route
server.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send("this is home route");
});

// Use the routes
server.use('/login', loginRoute);
server.use('/signUp', signUpRoute);
server.use('/authorizeEmail', authorizationRoute);
server.use('/deleteUser', deleteUserRoute);
server.use('/sendEmail', sendEmailRoute);
server.use('/sendInquiries', sendInquiriesRoute);
server.use('/adminLogin', adminLoginRoute);
server.use("/checkToken", tokenRoute);

server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});


Morever if i send subsequent request to the following endpoint
import express from 'express';
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';

dotenv.config();

const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    const token = req.cookies.jwtToken;
    console.log(token)
    
    if (!token) {
        return res.status(401).json({ error: "Authentication token missing" });
    }

    jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET, (err, user) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(403).json({ error: "Invalid or expired token" });
        }

        return res.sendStatus(200)
    });
});

export default router;
i get "Authentication token missing" in the console                                moreover in inspect/Application tab there is no cookie

How did you see there wasn't your cookie ?

from the inspect tab and when i do this  console.log(token) in an endpoint it gives me undefined in the console

You can't check this way, it returns undefined because it's httpOnly. Take a look within Storage instead

This question is similar to: I am unable to set the cookies received from the response. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

i tried looking within the Storage within the inspect tab but there is nothing there

yes it is similar to that question but i have tried everything told there and its still not working

Make Sure Axios Sends Cookies with Requests
Add withCredentials: true in your Axios request to ensure cookies are sent with cross-origin requests.
Update your frontend code like this:
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (loading) return;
    setLoading(true); // Start loading

    try {
        const response = await axios.post(
            `${import.meta.env.VITE_BACKEND_URI}/adminLogin`,
            { Id: id, Password: password },
            { withCredentials: true } // Ensures cookies are sent with the request
        );

        if (response.status === 200) {
            navigate('/Home');
        }
    } catch (error) {
        setError(error.response?.data?.error || "Login failed. Please check your internet or try again later.");
    } finally {
        setLoading(false);
    }
};


still not working even after adding {withCredentials:true}
